# Dynamically fill Quiz Form from Database (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, forms, dynamic-programming

I am trying to make a quiz program that will fetch the questions and their choices from a MySQL Database, and display them as a form for the user to fill. The user (upon filling all fields) will then submit. There is no scoring here, the answers are just stored in the database with that user's registration ID (This is because some answers are open, i.e : The user has to physically type in the answer, so this will be evaluated later).

The structure of my tables are (I will post the create query since the table looks distorted and hard to read) :

Table 1 : This contains the **q_id** (Each question has a unique ID), **question** (The actual question), **quiz_id** (The id of the quiz that this question belongs to; There are multiple quizzes!), **active** (A simple "y" or "n" field that checks if this question is active. If it isnt, the question is not added to the form), and **type** ('c' for single choice, 'm' for Multiple choice, and 'o' for open/user text input)

```
CREATE  TABLE `db_test`.`insr_questions` (
  `q_id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `question` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `quiz_id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `active` CHAR(1) NOT NULL ,
  `type` CHAR(1) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );
```

Table 2: This contains the fields **a_id** (which is the unique ID of the answer choice), **choice** (Which is the actual answer choice), **question_id** (Which is the question ID that these answer choices belong to), and **active** (Which is same as above)

```
 CREATE  TABLE `db_test`.`insr_answers` (
  `a_id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `choice` VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL ,
  `question_id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `active` CHAR(1) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );
```

So the idea here is to retrieve a **quiz_id** and then delve into the questions table and retrieve all the questions that belong to that quiz_id, and then take each question, and retrieve all the answers that belong to that question_id. These will then have to be displayed in a php form.

Any pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated!

(I am currently reading up on different ways in which this can be done, being a novice in php, so I will add any other code that I work on, to this question!)

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [JOINS in MySQL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp), this way you can get the questions and answers in one go:

```
SELECT * FROM insr_questions q 
LEFT JOIN insr_answers a ON q.q_id = a.question_id 
WHERE q.active = 1 AND q.quiz_id = 0
```

And then use mysql_fetch_array to loop through the results. (notice i used the table aliasses q and a, this reduces typing and used for the quiz_id an arbitrary number)

Comment: This is good advice, thank you! But the query writing isn't so much of a worry for me, it is the php code to create the form as per the question/answer structure that has me stumped! Could you please offer some guidance in that area?

Answer (score 0):

Finished the problem with the following algorithm :

```
Begin Loop (i from 0 to count(questions) )
  Create TextArea
  Textarea.Value = Question[i]
  Get count(answers) for Question[i]
  Get Type of Answer
  Case(c)
    Begin Loop (n from 0 to count(answers) )
      Create Radio Button[n]
      Radiobutton[n].Value = Choice[n]
    End Loop
  Case(m)
    Begin Loop (n from 0 to count(answers) )
      Create Checkbox[n]
      Checkbox[n].Value = Choice[n]
    End Loop
  Case(o)
    Create TextArea
  End Case
End Loop
```